2,3,6,7 to get 10
How do I use the numbers 2,3,6,7 to get 10? You can also make numbers like 23 or 76 too.

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

Could you also specify what operations are allowed? Are exponents allowed? Are factorials allowed?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Using basic operations and a two digit number:

 $6\times7-32=42-32=10$


Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our attribution policy; that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.

Just using the four basic operations:

 $(7-2)\times\frac 63$


Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our attribution policy; that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.

You didn't specify whether exponents and factorials are allowed so I'm assuming they are. I found 2 answers:
1:

 $ 3^2 - 6 + 7$

2:

 $ 7 + 2 + \frac{3!}{6} $


Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our attribution policy; that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism. (I mean, you must know the policy; you linked it yourself)

@bobble I didn't know answering such questions is also not allowed. I guess I'll read through the policy again to see if there is anything else I missed

The policy is to close such questions. Closing prevents answers. This has no effect if the question gets answers before closing. Thus, users are encouraged to not answer questions which are close-worthy. I'm not sure if it's an official policy or not, but it's my strong opinion. My comment was to reflect that strong opinion.
